# AlarmManager not firing on M devices

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm working on a tracking service. Every time a worker presses "Check-in", a service will start running in the background, taking user's location every hour. It'll stop until the user presses "check-out", or if working day has finished; I'm using WakefulBroadcastReceiver and a Service.

First, I call my TrackingBroadcast after Check-in Button is pressed:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackingBroadcast.class);
intent.putExtra("id_punto", id_punto);
intent.putExtra("hora_salida", horario_salida);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then, in my TrackingBroadcast

```
public static final int BROADCAST_ID = 1000;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent){
    int id_punto = intent.getIntExtra("id_punto", 0);
    String hora_salida = intent.getStringExtra("hora_salida");
    rescheduleAlarm(ctx, id_punto, hora_salida);
}

private void rescheduleAlarm(Context ctx, int id_punto, String hora_salida){
    Intent serviceIntent      = new Intent(ctx, TrackingService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("id_punto", id_punto);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("horario_salida", hora_salida);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("service_id", BROADCAST_ID);

    // Empezamos servicio, manteniendo el teléfono despierto mientras se llama
    startWakefulService(ctx, serviceIntent);
}
```

Finally, in my TrackingService, I reschedule my TrackingBroadcast. This method is called every time location changes, so that I can get latest user's location (I'm using **FusedLocationApi**)

```
private void rescheduleAlarm(){
    long startTime, repeatingTime;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackingBroadcast.class);
    intent.putExtra("id_punto", id_punto);
    intent.putExtra("hora_salida", hora_salida);

    Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime     = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    repeatingTime = 1000 * 60 * 60 ; // Una hora

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, BROADCAST_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    // Si versión del SO es > a Marshmallow, permetirá despertar teléfono incluso si está IDLE mode
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Alarma activada para SDK >= 23");
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                startTime + repeatingTime,
                pendingIntent
        );
    } else {
        // Si es Lollipop, activadrá la alarma normal
        Log.d("TAG", "Alarma activada para SDK < 23");
        alarmManager.setExact(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                startTime + repeatingTime,
                pendingIntent
        );
    }

    TrackingBroadcast.completeWakefulIntent(broadcastIntent);
}
```

This is working fine on Lollipop devices, and it is also working on my Nexus 6P with Android O Dev Prev 4...

I don't know what is happening, because if my app is working with Android O's DOZE mode, why is not working with Android M devices?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the `WAKE_LOCK` permission in your manifest? Can you confirm whether the alarm triggers when dozed but just doesn't complete? The wake lock is released automatically (I believe) when the `onRecieve` method terminates. So if you're running something on a new thread, then the wake lock may be released prior to completion of the task. If that is the case then you could manually acquire and release the wake lock (I know `WakefulBroadcastReciever` is supposed to do this). It could also be the model of phone you're using rather than Android M itself.

Comment: Yes, I do have `WAKE_LOCK` in my manifest. I can't confirm if my alarm was called and not completed. I'm using **Countly** to log user's actions, but this doesn't work within a `service` or `WakefulBroadcastReciever`.
I was thinking the same as you (about phone's model), but is not working on samsung devices...